# pass json array argument to php via command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I need to pass a parameter in JSON format to a php file via command line

my_file.php

```
<?php

print_r($argv);

die;
```

This works as expected (I will then parse the argument received)

```
php my_file.php my_param=player?query={"attributes":[{"first_name":"john"}]}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => command.php
    [1] => my_param=player?query={attributes:[{first_name:john}]}
)
```

But if I add a second item to the attributes array, then it no longer works as expected

```
php my_file.php my_param=player?query={"attributes":[{"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe"}]}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => command.php
    [1] => my_param=player?query={attributes:[first_name:john]}
    [2] => my_param=player?query={attributes:[last_name:doe]}
)
```

I want it to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => command.php
    [1] => my_param=player?query={attributes:[{first_name:john,last_name:doe}]}
)
```

Comment: Try quoting your arg (single-quotes)... `php my_file.php 'my_param=...'`

Comment: `php my_file.php my_param=player?query='{"attributes":[{"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe"}]}'`  as @phil said

Comment: @IanKenney err, no. The quotes go around the whole arg

Comment: @Phil Yes, that did the trick!

Comment: Consider using options:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php